# ad hoc scanner just wont work

Tags: operators, adhoc

So far i have this code that is suppose to be an ad hoc scanner, im not sure where exactly the problem is because i get a very odd error in the output.txt file. it all starts when the program hits the left parenthesis, is there somthing wrong with my checkforoperators function? i have looked but have found little and have even asked others, but no reall luck as to what the problem is.

the input file contains this

```
read A1
read A2
sum:=(A1-33)+A2*5.5
write sum
write (A1+A2)/2
```

and the output file is SUPPOSE to look like this

```
read
A1
read
A2
Sum
:=
(
A1
-
33
)
+
A2
*
5.5
write
sum
write
(
A1
+
A2
)
/
2
```

heres the main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

// This program is an ad-hoc scanner.
// It will recognize tokens and seperate them.
// this language will NOT DISTINGUISH between uppercase or lowercase.

    void stripSpacing(string &);
    void checkForCommands();
    void checkForLetters();
    void checkForOperators();
    void checkForAssignment();
    void checkForDecimal();
    void checkForDigit();

    int x1 = 0;
    int x2 = 0;
    int vars[10];
    // Only for demonstration purposes, we could use a dynamic array for larger purposes.

    string holder;
    // used to hold the current string before processing.

    fstream handling;
    // file handling from other libraries.
    fstream output;

    char temp1[1];
    char temp2[1];
    int x = 0;
    int xtemp = 0;

int main()
{
    output.open("output.txt");
    handling.open("input.txt");

    if (handling.is_open())
    {
        while (!handling.eof())
        {
            dcom:
            getline (handling,holder);
            if(holder[x] == '/' && holder[x+1] == '/')
            {
                cout << "This line has only comments.... REMOVED :)" << endl;
                //do nothing :)
                goto dcom;
            }
            cout << endl;
            stripSpacing(holder);
            cout << "The line is this long after removing spaces: " << holder.length() << endl;
            cout << "The line contains: " << holder << endl;
            cout << endl;

            while(holder.length() != x)
            {
                // let's check for commands, such as read write or sum.
                checkForOperators();
                checkForAssignment();
                checkForDecimal();
                checkForDigit();
                checkForCommands();
                checkForLetters();
            }
            output << "\n";

            x=0;
        }

    handling.close();
    output.close();
    return 0;
    }
}

void stripSpacing(string &str)
{
    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
        if (str[i]==' ')
        {
            str.erase(i,1);
            i--;
        }
}
void checkForOperators()
{
    if(holder[x] == '(' || holder[x] == ')'|| holder[x] == '+' || holder[x] == '-' || holder[x] == '*' ||holder[x] == '/')
    {
        output << holder[x] + "\n";
        x++;
    }
    cout << "checkForOpertors" << endl;
}

void checkForCommands()
{
    xtemp = x;
    if(holder[x] == 'w')
    {
        x++;
        if(holder[x] == 'r')
        {
            x++;
            if(holder[x] == 'i')
            {
                x++;
                if(holder[x] == 't')
                {
                    x++;
                    if(holder[x] == 'e')
                    {
                        x++;
                        output << "write\n"; goto stop;
                    }else{x=xtemp; goto stop;}
                }else{x=xtemp; goto stop;}
            }else{x=xtemp; goto stop;}
        }else{x=xtemp; goto stop;}
    }

    if(holder[x] == 'r')
    {
        x++;
        if(holder[x] == 'e')
        {
            x++; 
            if(holder[x] == 'a')
            {
                x++;
                if(holder[x] == 'd')
                {
                    x++;
                    output << "read\n"; goto stop;
                }else{x=xtemp; goto stop;}
            }else{x=xtemp; goto stop;}
        }else{x=xtemp; goto stop;}
    }

    if(holder[x] == 's')
    {
        x++;
        if(holder[x] == 'u')
        {
            x++;
            if(holder[x] == 'm')
            {
                x++;
                output << "sum\n"; goto stop;
            }else{x=xtemp; goto stop;}
        }else{x=xtemp; goto stop;}
    }

    stop:
    cout << "checkForCommand" << endl;
}

void checkForLetters()
{
    if(isalpha(holder[x]))
    {
        output << holder[x];
        x++;
    }
    cout << "checkForLetters" << endl;
}

void checkForAssignment()
{
    if(holder[x] == ':')
    {
        x++;
        if(holder[x] == '=')
        {
            output << ":=\n";
            x++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "ERROR!!! NO : BEFORE =" << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "checkForAssign" << endl;
}

void checkForDecimal()
{
    if(holder[x] == '.')
    {
        x++;
        if(isdigit(holder[x]))
        {
            output << '.';
            x--;
        }
    }
    cout << "checkForDeci" << endl;
}

void checkForDigit()
{
    if(isdigit(holder[x]))
    {
        output << holder[x];
        x++;
    }
    cout << "checkForDig" << endl;
}
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: What happens when you step through your code line by line?

Comment: okay basically, when i run through my code, it scans for everything listed in the checkforetc operators. as it reads through the text file input, it is suppose to check for everything listed in the input, commands, characters, etc, then it outputs then in token form in the output file, but when i run the code, in the output file all im getting is the first part of the correct out put all the way down until i reach that first left parenthesis right after sum:= and when it hits that it outputs some weird stuff and then a bunch of periods. i think somthing maybe wrong with my checkforoperatos